# Excel IF statement from drop down menu gives error / wrong data type

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create an IF statement from a drop down menu where I have made the options Yes or No.

I have gone for: `=IF(B2=''Yes'',D5,0)`. This is giving me an error.

However when I try: `=IF(B2=Yes,D5,0)`, it says I have used the wrong data type. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the error you receive? What type of drop-down you have. I suppose drop-down is in / linked to B2, is that right? what happens if you type `=B2`, or `=ISTEXT(B2)`?

Answer (score 2):

You're using 2 single quotes marks, `''`, which also gives me an error.

You need to use double quote `"`. Copy and paste the code below in your Excel sheet.

```
=IF(B2="Yes",D5,0)
```